# Scheme convert entry into a list

Tags: list, input, scheme, racket

how do i convert an input to a list?

```
(define (conjuger v t p)
    (cond ((equal? t '(present)) (present (radical v) p))
```

I want to input the V as a word, but i am forced to type it as a list for the program to work. Is there a way to have scheme do this:

```
'(m a n g e r) => '(manger)

'(manger) => '(m a n g e r)
```

Comment: It's a little unusual to break apart symbols like this.  Is there a particular reason why the input isn't coming in as a string, for example?

Answer (score 4):

Try this for the first part:

```
(define (implode lst)
  (string->symbol
   (apply string-append
          (map symbol->string lst))))

(list (implode '(m a n g e r)))
; => '(manger)
```

And this for the second part:

```
(define (explode itm)
  (map (lambda (c) (string->symbol (string c)))
       (string->list
        (symbol->string itm))))

(explode (car '(manger)))
; => '(m a n g e r)
```

Notice that in your code you're using *symbols*, not strings. I wrote my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This is the version of Nils M. Holm, Sketchy Scheme. 4.5th edition (Raleigh 2011) p. 72–74:

```
(define (compose f g)
  (lambda x
    (f (apply g x))))

(define symbol->list
  (compose string->list symbol->string))

(define (explode item)
  (map (lambda (item)
         (string->symbol
          (string item)))
       (symbol->list item)))

(define (implode item)
  (letrec
      ((sym->char
        (lambda (item)
          (let ((string (symbol->string item)))
            (if (not (= (string-length string) 1))
                (error "bad symbol -- IMPLODE")
                (string-ref string 0))))))
    (string->symbol
     (list->string
      (map sym->char item)))))

scheme@(guile-user)> (explode 'foo)
$1 = (f o o)
scheme@(guile-user)> (implode '(b a r))
$2 = bar
```

Older versions of the book are avaible [online](http://www.bcl.hamilton.ie/~nmh/t3x.org/zzz/) for free in pdf or html format under the title »sketchy lisp« (dealing explicitly with Scheme, though). The problem of splitting symbols into lists and vice versa is treated in chapter 2.5.

Comment: I didn't know those procedures had well-known names. I'm borrowing the names for my answer, if you don't mind :)

Comment: @Óscar: I don’t know whether the names are well known (I couldn’t find them in Guile or Racket), but they are quite nice. You’re welcome. :)